# Facebook extended access token doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm using the read_stream permission to get comments,likes and shares info by a user on a particular page. For that I need a long lived access token as I need to poll the servers and update them periodically.
But, when I do this:

```
  if($user){
   $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken(); 
    $access_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
 function xy(){
xx...
}
```

I always get only a token that expires in one hour.

Is there something I'm missing?
I'm using the PHP SDK

Comment: I've had a similar issue (not using PHP, just REST calls).  Even though the token says (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) it never expires, today it expired (I created the token today, also).

Comment: Not the same case with me, it does expire within one hour!